# "inserting the dynamically generated rows into the table"

Tags: c#

I am bit new in the c# programming, so I got stuck at one place. Need your help.
Actually through javascript I am generating table(4 columns) rows(having textboxes so that user can give inputs) as per as the user button click. As the number of rows are not fixed and we dont have the exact name of the textboxes so now my problem is how should we insert these rows into the sqlserver table?

should I use simply the loop for generating the name of the Textboxes for every user button click? and once we got the name for all controls can we insert these all through a single insert statement by using loop?

warm regrads,
ammy

Answer (score 0):

If you're using just a regular html table `add 'runat="server"' Tag with JS` as well as html form controls then just `change TableRow to HtmlTableRow` and `TextBox to HtmlInputText`. All of those controls are in the `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace`.

Assuming you're using the Table server control then it's just:

```
foreach (TableRow row in table.Rows)
    {
       var col2 = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
       //Do DB inserting stuff here With col2
       string stringToInsert=  col2 .Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm asuming you're using MVC..
You can start by creating a model such as:

```
public class YourModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Users> users { get; set; }
}
```

Than create a view and add the rows dynamically by script given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var Rows = 1;
// We already got the 0 element as html so start from 1

function AddUser() {
    $("#UserTable").append('<tr>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="users[' + Rows + '].Name" style="width:100px;" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="users[' + Rows + '].Surname" style="width:100px;" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="users[' + Rows + '].Age" style="width:50px;" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="users[' + Rows + '].Date" style="width:70px;" /></td>' +
        '</tr>');
    // Add datepicker (this is an optional jQueryUI stuff)
    $('input[name="users[' + Rows + '].Date"]').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy.mm.dd' });
    // Go to next row
    Rows = Rows + 1;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Create an empty row on load
    AddUser();
    // Than on each click add another row
    $('input[type=button]').click(function(){ AddUser(); });
});

</script>

<div>
    <table id="UserTable">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="user[0].Name" style="width:100px;" value="Berker" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="user[0].Surname" style="width:100px;" value="Yüceer" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="user[0].Age" style="width:50px;" value="24" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="user[0].Date" style="width:70px;" value="2012.12.11" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />
</div>
```

fiddle for the script: http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/YFecD/

From your controller you can get the values as show below:

```
// Thanks to LinqToSql you can define ur Sql-DB this way
YourDBDataContext db = new YourDBDataContext();

//
// POST: /YourForm/Edit
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(YourModel model)
{
    try
    {
        // if users not empty..
        if (model.users != null)
        {
            // Each User in Users
            foreach (var user in model.users)
            {   // Save it to your Sql-DB
                db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
        // Return
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Error", new { ErrorMessage = "Message[" + ex.Message + "] - Source[" + ex.Source + "] - StackTrace[" + ex.StackTrace + "] - Data[" + ex.Data + "]" });
    }
}

//
// GET: /YourForm/Error
public ActionResult Error(String ErrorMessage)
{
    ViewData["Error"] = ErrorMessage;
    return View();
}
```

simple as this!